# Kotlinx - Use different root View for Views

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Within my current project, I'm inflating Views like this. I override a `init` method, which allows me to setup the `View`, and get a reference to it.

```
class MyView(context: Context) : View(context), MyWidget {

    private lateinit var myView: View

    override fun init(viewGroup: ViewGroup) {
        myView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_view, viewGroup)

        myView.textView.text = "Welcome"
        myView.nextButton.text = "Sign In"
    }
}
```

However, the issue is that if I'm using `kotlinx`, I need to prefix all my `Views` with `myView.`.

```
myView.textView.text = "Welcome"
// instead of
textView.text = "Welcome"
```

Both are valid in the compiler's eyes, but if I forget to prefix it, it will crash at runtime.

Is there a way to tell `kotlinx` to use the `View` I have created, instead of the `View` I'm extending?

Comment: May be you shouldn't use `: View(context)`, but use `: View` with overridden constructors.

Comment: @Onik I'm not sure I follow, could you give me an example of how that would effect the issue I'm running into?

Comment: Moreover, you have a layout for `MyView`, so the the choice of extending `View` is unclear for me. I'd recommend to extend e.g. `FrameLayout` and inflate `layout_view` in constructor(s). By doing this you'd refer the layout's views by their names, e.g. `textView`, without any "prefix".

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
myView.apply { 
//set your views here without prefix
}
```

block to set your textviews

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. This isn't just for initialization, I have many references to the views throughout many functions.

Comment: I think you should consider extending `ViewGroup` (or root container for `R.layout.layout_view`). `ViewGroups` have `rootView`, which you tried to implement as a `myView`. Another option is to rewrite the view to be dynamically created in the code, rather than inflating from an xml. In the current state, adding your view twice to the same viewgroup will result in duplicated ids.